# Constants of universal derivation on an $R$-algebra $A$ under localization ($d: S^{-1}A \to S^{-1}\Omega_{A/R}$)

Tags: commutative-algebra, schemes, de-rham-cohomology, differential-algebra, differential-algebraic-equations

Suppose that $A$ is an $R$-algebra, with both $R, A$ integral domains.
Let $B = S^{-1}A$ be a localization of $A$.

Let
$$\partial_A: A \to M$$
$$\partial_B: B \to S^{-1}M$$
be an $R$-derivation on $A$ and its unique extension to $B$.

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2051634/constants-in-localizations-of-a-differential-ring)
it is asked whether, in the case of $A=M$, the obvious inclusion
$$\mathrm{ker}(\partial_A) \subset \mathrm{ker}(\partial_B)$$
is an equality.

A counterexample was provided: the derivation $D = x\partial_x + y\partial_y$ on $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

My question regards the $\textit{universal derivation}$
$$d:A \to \Omega_{A/R}$$

and when its constants are preserved under localization. In a sense this captures the common constants under all derivations.

If $R$ is not a field, and $B$ contains some inverses of $R$ (measured by $S_0 := S \cap R$), then this will clearly enlarge the constants. Further, if $S_1 := S \cap \mathrm{ker}(d_A)$
$$\mathrm{ker}(d_A) \subset S_0^{-1}\mathrm{ker}(d_A) \subset S_1^{-1}\mathrm{ker}(d_A) \subset \mathrm{ker}(d_B)$$
So I would like to ask, **under what conditions will this second inclusion be an equality**:
$$S_1^{-1}\mathrm{ker}(d_A) = \mathrm{ker}(d_B)$$

which I might paraphrase as: when are the constants of the localization no larger than expected from localizing?

I am interested in the general answer (and even how much can be said in positive characteristic), but the most important case for me is when $\mathrm{Frac}(A)/\mathrm{Frac}{R}$ is a field extension of transcendence degree $1$.

The motivation comes from comparing relative de Rham cohomology of a scheme with the cohomology of open subschemes.

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, there is a $S^{-1}A$-isomorphism $S^{-1}\Omega^1_{A/R} \cong \Omega^1_{B/R}$ compatible with the universal derivation.

Comment: @Mindlack Yes, you are correct, but I did not see how this gives me information about the kernel.

Comment: Oops, you’re right. What if $A=R[x]/P(x)$ (eg $R=\mathbb{Z}$) and $S=\{P’(x)\}$? Then $B$ is étale over $R$ so $d_B=0$, but $d_A$ usually isn’t…

Comment: @Mindlack Hmm yes, good point. I think I need to restrict the localization somehow. I need to think about this some more. Thank you.